# Reading VMFS data from ZFS snapshot

Tags: filesystems, zfs, esxi, iscsi

I am wondering about something and maybe someone can give me a clue. If I have a server running ZFS plus an iSCSI target for my VMware ESXi box. Would ZFS snapshots of the iSCSI virtual block device without VMFS? Or would I require VMFS since the block file system of the iSCSI device was VMFS.

Follow me?